# Python: how to merge multiple dataframes with conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe contains two different `IDs` lists.

```
df
    ID1  ID2
0    0   35
1    0   35
2    1   33
3    2   27
```

Then I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` that contain the coordinates of such `IDs`.

```
df1
     ID1   x    y
0     0   1.3  2.3
1     1   2.5  7.2
3     2   4.5  4.5


df2
     ID2   x    y
0    27   3.6  4.5
1    33   3.3  2.3
2    35   2.3  2.5
```

I would like to to assign to `df` the coordinates of `ID1` if it is repeated more times and the coordinates of `ID2` if `ID1` only appears once in `df`

At the end I would like something like that

```
df
    ID1  ID2    x     y
0    0   35    1.3   2.3
1    0   35    1.3   2.3
2    1   33    3.3   2.3
3    2   27    3.6   4.5
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the trick:

```
df=df.merge(df1).merge(df2,on='ID2',suffixes=['_id1','_id2'])

mask=df.groupby('ID1').transform('count')['ID2']

df['x']=np.where(mask>1,df['x_id1'],df['x_id2'])
df['y']=np.where(mask>1,df['y_id1'],df['y_id2'])

df[['ID1','ID2','x','y']]


   ID1  ID2    x    y
0    0   35  1.3  2.3
1    0   35  1.3  2.3
2    1   33  3.3  2.3
3    2   27  3.6  4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out

```
df3 = (df[df.duplicated(subset='ID1')]).merge(df1, how='left')
df4 = (df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID1')).merge(df2, on='ID2')
df5 = df3.merge(df4, how='outer').drop_duplicates(subset='ID1', keep='first')
df5.reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
```